# Sub query inside a decode statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in a table like below:

```
EMPLOYEE_NUM              START_DTM             END_DTM
47567567446          5/9/2019 12:00:00 PM   
76475676575675756    5/10/2019 12:00:00 PM  5/10/2019 11:59:59 PM
456756765767         5/3/2019 12:00:00 PM   5/8/2019 11:59:59 PM
74676576764565       5/2/2019 12:00:00 PM   5/8/2019 11:59:59 PM
98695689576          5/1/2019 12:00:00 PM
```

I want retrieve  employee_num with below conditions:

if there are any entries with NULL as end_dtm, 
then print employee_num with max(start_dtm) and whose end_dtm is null

if there are no entries with NULL as end_dtm, 
then print employee_num with end_dtm=max(end_dtm)

I tried with

```
select 
decode(select count(1) from employee where end_dtm is null,
       0,
       select employee_num where end_dtm=(select max(end_dtm) from employee),
       select employee_num where start_dtm=(select max(start_dtm) from employee where end_dtm is null),
       ) from dual
```

Looks like this is not a valid query.
Could anybody please help.

Comment: You've got `where` clauses before the `from employee` statement in two of those sub-queries. The `where` clause needs to come after `from employee`.

Comment: In addition to what @JoshEller said, the subqueries - used as individual values - must be enclosed in parentheses of their own; that is mandatory, not optional. Also, are you sure that those subqueries will return at most one value in each case? If not, the logic itself is wrong, regardless of the code.

Comment: Further to my last point (about the logic itself): What if, for example, there are two (or more) employees with NULL end_dtm, with the same start_dtm, which happens to be the maximum start_dtm in the entire table? In that case there are two (or more) employee numbers to be returned, not exactly one such number. So, then, in your business problem (forget about computers completely for now), what should you return? One of the employee numbers, perhaps the largest or the smallest one? ALL the employee numbers that are "tied" in your comparison? Something else?

Comment: @mathguy. You are right. In the case you mentioned above I need any one for which I would go for rownum =1. But I don't want to complicate by adding that. Let's assume for now. The dates are unique

Comment: @Vijay . . . Sample data *and desired results* would help.  The description of the logic may not be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you must distinguish between END_DTM being null vs. non-null first, and only then consider either END_DTM or START_DTM for further ordering.

The function NVL2 is exactly what you need for the first part. It takes three arguments; it returns the second argument when the first is non-null, and the third argument when it's null. So: NVL2(END_DTM, 1, 0) will return 1 when the date is non-null and 0 when it is null. And then, you can use NVL2 again, to choose END_DTM when it is not null, but START_DTM when it is null.

You can then use this in defining ROW_NUMBER(), in the ORDER BY clause, like so:

```
select [whatever]
from   
  ( select t.*, 
           row_number() over (order by nvl2(END_DTM, 1, 0),
                                       nvl2(END_DTM, END_DTM, START_DTM) desc) rn
    from   your_table t
  )
where  rn = 1
;
```

If END_DTM is always non-null (or if it is always null) then the first NVL2 value is constant, so the ordering is only by END_DTM (if END_DTM is always non-null), resp. by START_DTM (if END_DTM is always null). But if there is a mix of null and non-null END_DTM, then only those with null END_DTM are tied by the first ordering criterion, and then only those rows are considered for selecting the max START_DTM.

Comment: This is almost correct. But I would suggest a small modification.`order by nvl2(END_DTM, 1, 0), START_DTM desc` should be changed to `order by order by nvl2(END_DTM, 1, 0), NVL2(END_DTM,END_DTM,START_DTM) desc`

Comment: @Vijay - oh, I misread your requirement. You are right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would have used `analytical` function for this as following:

```
Select employee_num from
(Select t.employee_num
Sum(case when end_dtm is null then 1 end) as cnt,
Row_number() 
over (order by end_dtm desc nulls last) as end_dtm_rn,
Row_number() 
over (order by case when end_dtm is null then start_dtm end desc nulls last) as start_dtm_rn
From employee t)
Where case when cnt = 0 
then end_dtm_rn
Else start_dtm_rn end = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation and `case`:

```
select employee_num,
       (case when count(*) = count(end_dtm)  -- no nulls
             then max(end_dtm)
             else max(start_dtm)
        end)
from t
group by employee_num;
```

If you want this *per row* in the original data, use analytic functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by employee_num) = count(end_dtm) over (partition by employee_num)  -- no nulls
             then max(end_dtm) over (partition by employee_num)
             else max(start_dtm) over (partition by employee_num)
        end)
from t;
```

EDIT:

An alternative reading of what you want suggests that you want one `employee_num` subquery to your conditions.  If that is the case, then this is even simpler:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by (case when end_dtm is null then 1 else 2 end),  -- nulls first
               start_dtm desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: You misunderstood the requirement. max(start_dtm) is required in all cases; but if some rows have null end_dtm, then the max should only be over those rows. Then: all the employee numbers are distinct in the inputs; what's with the GROUP BY in your first attempt? -1 as this is not useful.

Comment: @mathguy . . . The downvote is just rude if you want to say that the responder misunderstood the question.  A comment is quite sufficient.